# Establishing a new react app with existing express webpage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes

I have a website made from nodejs-express and ejs , it has 5 pages home , events , about ,developer ,gallery , so all these pages are delivered using ejs. Now I need to create a web app using react and have it as another page of the website ,I searched throughout the internet i found no articles mentioning this particular scenario. 
Please note **I dont want my root route to be the react app** , when i get a GET request on "/client" I need the react app (client) to load up.

My current senario is expressed in this sand box 
https://codesandbox.io/s/integrate-react-app-4dwu0?file=/src/index.js

Comment: This is really a tricky situation where you have to decide the rendering conditionally.
Could you provide a boilerplate code on codeSandbox or git? it will be easier to understand

Comment: @Sujan Thakare here is the link to the boiler plate sand box https://codesandbox.io/s/integrate-react-app-4dwu0?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you hosting this. You can deploy this at reactapp.yourdomain.com and set up a proxy for /client and route it to this one.

Comment: That's a great idea but is there any way to integrate such that we dont have to use a subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.
https://codesandbox.io/s/integrate-react-app-kb1c5?file=/reactAppFiles/index.html

You just need to set static files path and you have to send index.html.

it looks something like this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../reactAppFiles")));

app.get("/client", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "../reactAppFiles")
});
```

I hope this answers the question.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution I created a subdomain for my app rather than integrating it